# Specific attributes are being excluded from darts Element.setInnerHtml()

Tags: dart, frontend

I've encountered the following problem:

[image: I've encountered the following problem:]

Before mods may click 'duplicate', it isn't. I've searched the problem, found 'solutions', applied 'solutions' and they didn't work. So the question could be 'Why is my 'solution' not working?' or the question could be 'What is the actual solution?'

The responsible code for this is

```
querySelector("#element").setInnerHtml(some_element.outerHtml, treeSanitizer: NodeTreeSanitizer.trusted);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out to apply the sanitizer to the Element.

`Element element = new Element.html('<a data-tag="value">thing</a>'), treeSanitizer: NodeTreeSanitizer.trusted)`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone back recently to double check that is the best way, but we've ended up building a common NodeValidator that we keep up to date with our various custom attributes.

```
NodeValidator get commonValidator => _commonValidator;

/// Create a NodeValidator which passes common values.
final NodeValidator _commonValidator = new NodeValidatorBuilder.common()
  ..allowHtml5()
  ..allowInlineStyles()
  ..allowNavigation(_policy)
  ..allowImages()
  ..allowTextElements()
  ..allowElement("a", attributes: [
    "data-version",
    "data-attribute-add"])
  ..allowElement("div", attributes: [
    "data-sec"]);


foo.setInnerHtml(someOddHtml, validator: commonValidator);
```